# VTD parser performance vs DOM parser

Tags: xml, dom, vtd-xml

Good Day,

I have been trying to use VTD parser to improve the performance of my current DOM code,however, I still see DOM doing quicker parsing, please advise where I am going wrong.

Here is my code sample along with the sample XML

Sample XML -

```
<account-detail-result><status><status-code>0</status-code><status-message></status-message></status><result>
<line><entrydate><entryyear>2016</entryyear><entrymonth>02</entrymonth><entryday>16</entryday></entrydate><date><year>2016</year><month>02</month><day>15</day></date><merchant></merchant><description>DESCRIPTION1184076</description><transcode>246</transcode><rollingbalance>96.76</rollingbalance><indicator>DR</indicator><indicator>DR</indicator><txnseqno>366951</txnseqno><entrytime>50221</entrytime><isolbpendingtransaction>false</isolbpendingtransaction><valuedate>2016-02-15</valuedate><amount type='DR'>1000.00</amount><cardnumber></cardnumber></line>
```

VTD code -

```
            VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
            vg.setDoc(vResultString.getBytes());
            vg.parse(false);
            VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
            AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
            ap.selectXPath("/account-detail-result/status");
            while (ap.evalXPath() != -1) {
                if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD, "status-code")) {
                    if (vn.getText() != -1) {
                        vStatusCode = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText());
                        vn.toElement(VTDNav.PARENT);
                    }
                }
                if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD, "status-description")) {
                    if (vn.getText() != -1) {
                        vStatusDescription = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText());
                        vn.toElement(VTDNav.PARENT);
                    }
                }

            }
            ap.resetXPath();

            ap.selectXPath("/account-detail-result/result/line");
            while (ap.evalXPath() != -1) {
                do {
                    int venYear = 0;
                    int venMonth = 0;
                    int venDay = 0;
                    if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD, "entrydate")) {
                        if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD, "entryyear")) {
                            if (vn.getText() != -1) {
                                venYear = Integer.valueOf(vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText()));
                                vn.toElement(VTDNav.PARENT);
                            }
                        }
                        if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD, "entrymonth")) {
                            if (vn.getText() != -1) {
                                venMonth = Integer.valueOf(vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText()));
                                vn.toElement(VTDNav.PARENT);
                            }
                        }
                        if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD, "entryday")) {
                            if (vn.getText() != -1) {
                                venDay = Integer.valueOf(vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText()));
                                vn.toElement(VTDNav.PARENT);
                            }
                        }
                        vn.toElement(VTDNav.PARENT);
                        vPostedDateCol = new DateTime(venYear, venMonth, venDay, 0, 0, 0).toDate();
                    }

                    if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD, "date")) {
                        if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD, "year")) {
                            if (vn.getText() != -1) {
                                vYear = Integer.valueOf(vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText()));
                                vn.toElement(VTDNav.PARENT);
                            }
                        }
                        if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD, "month")) {
                            if (vn.getText() != -1) {
                                vMonth = Integer.valueOf(vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText()));
                                vn.toElement(VTDNav.PARENT);
                            }
                        }
                        if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD, "day")) {
                            if (vn.getText() != -1) {
                                vDay = Integer.valueOf(vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText()));
                                vn.toElement(VTDNav.PARENT);
                            }
                        }
                        vn.toElement(VTDNav.PARENT);
                    }

                    if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.FIRST_CHILD, "description")) {
                        if (vn.getText() != -1) {
                            vDescription = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText());
                        }
                    }
                    if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.NEXT_SIBLING, "transcode")) {
                        if (vn.getText() != -1) {
                            vTransactionCode = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText());
                        }
                    }
                    if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.NEXT_SIBLING, "rollingbalance")) {
                        if (vn.getText() != -1) {
                            vRollingBalance = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText());
                        }
                    }
                    if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.NEXT_SIBLING, "indicator")) {
                        if (vn.getText() != -1) {
                            System.out.println(vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText()));
                            vIndicator = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText());
                        }
                    }
                    if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.NEXT_SIBLING, "txnseqno")) {
                        if (vn.getText() != -1) {
                            vTxnSeqNo = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText());
                        }
                    }
                    if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.NEXT_SIBLING, "entrytime")) {
                        if (vn.getText() != -1) {
                            vEntryTime = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText());
                        }
                    }
                    if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.NEXT_SIBLING, "isolbpendingtransaction")) {
                        if (vn.getText() != -1) {
                            isOLBPendingTransaction = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText());
                        }
                    }
                    if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.NEXT_SIBLING, "valuedate")) {
                        if (vn.getText() != -1) {
                            valueDate = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText());
                        }
                    }
                    if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.NEXT_SIBLING, "status")) {
                        if (vn.getText() != -1) {
                            vStatus = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText());
                        }
                    }
                    if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.NEXT_SIBLING, "amount")) {
                        if (vn.getText() != -1 && vn.getAttrVal("type") != -1) {
                            vAmount = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText());
                            vAmountType = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getAttrVal("type"));
                        }
                    }
                    if (vn.toElement(VTDNav.NEXT_SIBLING, "cardnumber")) {
                        if (vn.getText() != -1) {
                            cardNumber = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText());
                        }
                    }
                    vn.toElement(VTDNav.PARENT);
                } while (vn.toElement(VTDNav.NEXT_SIBLING, "line"));
            }
            ap.resetXPath();
```

Comment: so as it stands your code works you just want it to be more efficient?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint, yes the code works, but I want to improve performance from the current DOM parsing that is happening on the sample XML, however, with my current code, VTD seems much slower, kindly advise

Comment: how big is your xml? how did you measure the performance?

Comment: Good Day @vtd-xml-author, the XML has 50000 + records, I invoke the service using SOAP UI and have put in code to measure the time elapsed from the start to the end, both for VTD and DOM parsing. VTD parser takes 1385ms while DOM takes 432ms.

Answer (score 0):

First I have a few comments on your code:

1. This line converts a in-memory string into a byte array. Why not just read it straight from a file using parseFile()?

   vg.setDoc(vResultString.getBytes());
2. This statement
   if (vn.getText() != -1) {
           vStatusCode = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText());
           vn.toElement(VTDNav.PARENT);
   }

   should have been

   if (vn.getText() != -1) {
       vStatusCode = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText());
    }
    vn.toElement(VTDNav.PARENT);

   Notice that in case getText() returns -1, the cursor won't return to its parent node, thus causing error in xpath logic.
3. The following statement

   venYear = Integer.valueOf(vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText()));

   can be rewritten as

   venYear = vn.parseInt(vn.getText()));

Other than that, I can't provide you more advice on how to tune your code without having a complete test case completed with your code and xml data.

Have you run the jdk's profiler to indentify the bottleneck?

Comment: many thanks for your comments, I will try using parsefile function now - does it works on the response from a rest service as this xml is an incoming response from a rest service?

Comment: Many thanks once again, parsehttpurl needs a URL string, while in my case the service is invoked through an invoker and we don't hit the URL directly. The other thing that I noticed that the maximum is taken for vg.parse(false) statement, is there anything that you can advise or would you want me to email you the zip files?

Comment: In that case you just have to read the byte array off the input input stream from the client making the connection, it should not be a big string to start with.